# sed substitution matches too many inputs

Tags: sed

This is my command:

```
echo "Test" | sed -f <(sed -e 's/.*/s,&,gI/' mydic)
```

The file `mydic` contains 2 columns delimited by commas (`,`)

```
a,AlphabetA  
.  
.   
.    
e,AlphabetE   
.   
.   
s,AlphabetS  
.   
t,AlphabetT   
test,testedd   
.   
.   
zebra,zebraaaa
```

The expect result is `testedd`, but I get `AlphabetTAlphabetEAlphabetSAlphabetT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo Test |sed -f <(sed 's/\(.*\),\(.*\)/s,\\<\1\\>,\2,gI/' mydic)
```

**\<** and **\>** indicate the start and end of a word, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You've asked it to replace "e" with "AlphabetE", which it's done correctly. I suspect you meant it to only consider whole words?

Try this:

```
echo "test" | sed -f <(sed -e 's/.*/s,\\<&\\>,gI/' mydic)
```

Edit: I noticed you had in fact dealt with the case issue.

Comment: Yes I meant the whole word and your command result is sed only the first alphabet. Result: AlphabetT>est

Comment: Ah, I see what I did wrong. Yes, @Peter has made the right adjustment.